# VF Extension class able to produce dynamic picklist options but unable to save selections

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

I have quite a dilemma here. I am very out of my league here so I am desperate for any help I can get.

I am currently attempting to create a multi-select picklist which will produce dynamic choices based upon the value of another field.

To complicate things, the picklist is based upon a component which makes the picklist the appearance of the type of Salesforce picklist used to select tabs to put on a menu (with two columns - options in the left and selections in the right).

Here is a rundown of the elements involved :

Object : Policy_Profile__c
Field whose value is being used to query the dynamic list : Vendor__c
Field which is populated to contain the selections : Products_Affected3__c

The code will properly produce the correct selections through the query which is run in the extension class, but it will not save correctly or populate the Products_Affected3__c field with the selections made.

This is the error which is being produced in the debug. It is actually coming from the VF component which is being used to create the picklist by maintaining a list whose values are supposed to be moved into the Products_Affected3__c field upon save :

```
11:01:32.053 (53649053)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
11:01:32.053 (53660697)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|MultiselectCompController set(rightOptionsHidden,ProductAlpha&ProductAlpha&ProductBeta&ProductBeta)
11:01:32.053 (53709017)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:01:32.053 (53769173)|USER_DEBUG|[43]|DEBUG|FLAG ########ProductAlpha&ProductAlpha&ProductBeta&ProductBeta
11:01:32.053 (53797049)|USER_DEBUG|[44]|DEBUG|VALUE ########ProductAlpha&ProductAlpha&ProductBeta&ProductBeta
11:01:32.053 (53905293)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:01:32.054 (54055383)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

The problem seems to be happening right after my FLAG### and VALUE### debug statements. My RIGHTOPTIONS2#### debug statement is never produced in the debug log so I'm guessing it's error-ing right at the setOptions(RightOptions2,value) line. Here is the VF component in which that error is occurring. (although I think the true problem is happening in the VF extension class which I'll show after this).

```
/*
* MultiselectCompController synchronizes the values of the hidden elements to the
* SelectOption lists.
*/
public with sharing class MultiselectCompController {

    public MultiselectCompController() {

    }


    public MultiselectCompController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    // SelectOption lists for public consumption
    public SelectOption[] leftOptions { get; set; }
    public SelectOption[] rightOptions2 { get; set; }

    // Parse &-separated values and labels from value and 
    // put them in option
    private void setOptions(SelectOption[] options, String value) {
        options.clear();
        String[] parts = value.split('&');
        for (Integer i=0; i<parts.size()/2; i++) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(parts[i*2], 'UTF-8'), 
              EncodingUtil.urlDecode(parts[(i*2)+1], 'UTF-8')));
        }
    }

    // Backing for hidden text field containing the options from the
    // left list
    public String leftOptionsHidden { get; set {
           leftOptionsHidden = value;
           setOptions(leftOptions, value);
        }
    }

    // Backing for hidden text field containing the options from the
    // right list
    public String rightOptionsHidden { get; set {
           rightOptionsHidden = value;
           System.debug('FLAG ########'+rightOptionsHidden);
           System.debug('VALUE ########'+value);

           setOptions(rightOptions2, value);
           System.debug('RIGHTOPTIONS2 ########'+rightOptions2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main class being used as the VF extension :

```
public class PolicyProfileVFControllerEdit
{
private final Policy_Profile__c main;
public String rightOptionsHidden { get; set; }
public String leftOptionsHidden { get; set; }
public String selectedMulPickKeyTech{get;set;} 
public string lookupid{get;set;}
public String message { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> options { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> selectedSubs2 { get; set; }
public String selectedItems { get; set; }
public String mainid {get;set;}
public String coid {get;set;}    
    public PolicyProfileVFControllerEdit(apexpages.standardcontroller controller)
        {
        this.main = (Policy_Profile__c) controller.getRecord();
        }

    public pageReference  execute()
        {
        return null;
        }

    public list<selectoption> getitems()
        {
        lookupid=main.Vendor__c;
        mainid=main.id;
        //Set<String> selectedItems = new Set<String>();
        selectedItems=main.Products_Affected3__c;
        coid = main.id;
        selectedMulPickKeyTech=main.Products_Affected3__c;

        List<selectoption> options= new list<selectoption>();
        if(lookupid != null)
            {
                    if(selectedMulPickKeyTech !=null)
                    {
                    //selectedMulPickKeyTech=selectedMulPickKeyTech.replace('[','');                
                    //selectedMulPickKeyTech=selectedMulPickKeyTech.replace(']','');

                    String[] selectedvalues = selectedMulPickKeyTech.split(',');

                    selectedSubs2 = new list<SelectOption>();
                    for (String selectedvalue: selectedvalues) 
                        {
                        selectedSubs2.add(new SelectOption(selectedvalue,selectedvalue));
                        }

                     }   

           Vendor_Profile__c a =[select name , (select name from Vendor_Products__r) from Vendor_Profile__c where id =:lookupid];
                for(Vendor_Product__c s : a.Vendor_Products__r)
                    {
                        //check that selected items dont already contain the keys
                        //if(!selectedItems.contains(s.name))
                    options.add(new SelectOption(s.name,s.name));
                    }
            }

            else
            options.add(new SelectOption('None','None'));
            return options;
        }

    public PageReference save()
        {
        message = null ;       
        Boolean first = true;
           for ( SelectOption so : selectedSubs2 ) 
            {
                if (first) 
                    {
                    message = message ;
                    }
                    message = message + ', ' + so.getValue() ;
                    first = false;
            }        
                message = message.removeStart('null, ');
                message = message.normalizeSpace();
                message = '['+message+']';
                main.Products_Affected3__c=message;
        System.debug('message ########'+message);
        update main;

      System.debug('main ID ########'+coid);

      PageReference pr = new PageReference('/a7w/o');

          pr.setRedirect(true);
          return pr;

        }
}
```

Again, I'm out of my league here. I am trying like crazy to figure it out. I would be extremely grateful for any help I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: @Rao - Thank you very much for the help. I put rightOptions2 = new list<SelectOption>(); into the controller just above the String[] parts = value.split('&');  line. However, I am now getting another 'Attempt to de-reference a null object' error and it is referencing line 69 in the extension class which is :  for ( SelectOption so : selectedSubs2 ). 

Do you have any ideas on that ? I think you're on the right track. I can't say enough how much I appreciate your input.

Comment: @James - thanks for the edit on the first post. I think I accidentally overlooked the first several lines of the extension class when I was formatting it to be code. Thanks.

Comment: no VF component included; you could also make all of our lives easier by eliminating irrelevant code to this problem

Comment: @crop1645- MultiselectCompController is the controller for the component. Which code have I supplied which is irrelevant ?

Comment: debugging these kind of issues is easier if the VF component (relevant sections) are also shown so we can understand what is being sent to the controller and how